# How to enter hide/show in password field in Laravel Breeze?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a Laravel Breeze application and I would like to know how to enter the show/hide password function of a login field that requires a password.

- `login.blade.php`

```
    <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password" />
```

- `text-input.blade.php`

```
    @props(['disabled' => false])
    
    <input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50']) !!}>
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic method for doing this is providing a clickable element which will toggle the `type` attribute of your `input` field between `password` (hidden) and `text` (visible).

This can be achieved simply with plain vanilla JavaScript. I've purposefully not used the `Breeze` markup to simplify things so you (and others) can see what is going on without that "muddying" the waters.

**HTML markup**

```
// This uses the bootstrap icons library for the eye icon to toggle
// https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css

<input type="password" id="password" />
<i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const togglePassword = document.querySelector("#togglePassword");

  togglePassword.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    // toggle the type attribute
    const type =
      password.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
    password.setAttribute("type", type);
    // toggle the eye / eye slash icon
    this.classList.toggle("bi-eye");
  });
});
```

Here is an example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/peppermintology/pen/jOxojXp) showing the above in action.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @props(['disabled' => false])

<div class="relative">
    <input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50']) !!}>

    <button type="button" class="absolute top-1/2 right-3 transform -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility(this)">
        <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19.4 4.6a9 9 0 1 0-12.73 12.73L12 17.47l2.73-2.74A9 9 0 0 0 19.4 4.6z"/>
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 9a3 3 0 0 1 0 6 3 3 0 0 1 0-6z"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    function togglePasswordVisibility(button) {
        var input = button.previousElementSibling;
        if (input.type === "password") {
            input.type = "text";
            button.classList.add("text-indigo-500");
        } else {
            input.type = "password";
            button.classList.remove("text-indigo-500");
        }
    }
</script>
```